# About seemingly similarly posed counting questions

Tags: combinatorics

> A permutation problem is a problem in which you are asked to count the number of permutations having $k$ symbols in some alphabet of $n$ symbols.

How is that different from the question below?

> In how many ways can we choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements?

Example problem:

> In how many ways can we choose $10$ elements from a set of $12$ elements?

Which I'd be tempted to solve as $12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = \text { the requested answer.}$

Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that in the first question you consider the ordering of the $k$ elements (permutations), while in the second question, you don't care about the ordering (combinations).

For example, if $k=2$ and our $n$ elements are $a,b,c$, then there are $3 \cdot 2$ permutations ($ab$, $ac$, $ba$, $bc$, $ca$, $cb$) but only $3$ combinations ($ab$, $ac$, $bc$).

The general formulas for the first and second questions respectively are
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)$$ and $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}.$$
Note that the number of combinations is simply the number of permutations divided by $k!$, since there are $k!$ permutations of each given combination.

Comment: You're correct. But how did you deduce from the way second question is posed that order doesn't matter?

Comment: @permutation I think the convention is that the word "choose" implies that order does not matter (unless otherwise specified). In fact, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}:= n!/(k!(n-k)!)$ is often read as "$n$ choose $k$."

Answer (score 0):

This question is not clear. Your answer correctly gives the number of ways one can choose 10 elements from a set of 12 elements, if the order of the elements is important. If the order of the elements is not important, we divide by the number of orderings, which is $10!$ The result is $${12\choose10}\equiv{12!\over10!2!}={12\times11\over2}=66$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first, it is clear that different orders matter, that abc is different from cba.  In the second and third, it is not clear whether order matters.  I would read them them that order does not matter.  In that case, your answer to the third is not correct as you have counted the orders as distinct.

Comment: In my textbook "In how many ways can we choose $6$ letters
from the English alphabet?" is a combinations problem. What gives away the fact(?) that it's not a permutations problem?

Comment: Choose (without reference to order) seems to mean you only pick a group of six of them.  I agree it is not entirely clear.